# SQL Alchemy check for duplicate records based on multiple values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I want to check for an existing row in my db instance based on attributes.

Here is my Model :

```py
class BasketModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'basket'
    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    org_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('organization.id'))
    first_attribute = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(2))
    second_attribute = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)
    ... # many more attributes
```

In my relational model, a new record is considered as duplicated if all its non key attributes (excepted from id which is unique) are equals.

```py
entityA = BasketModel(org_id=1, first_attribute="Hello", second_attribute="World")
entityB = BasketModel(org_id=1, first_attribute="Hello", second_attribute="World")
entityA == entityB # Should be True
```

Now if I want to add a new record I can simply do (thanks to ORM abstraction) :

```
session.add(entityA)
```

But if I want to check for an existing record based on values I have to check each single field (which is very ugly, not scallable and frustrating) :

```py
# create entity A
entityA = BasketModel(org_id=1, first_attribute="Hello", second_attribute="World")

# add entity A 
session.add(entityA)
session.flush()
session.commit()

# Now A is in the Database

#create entity B
entityB = BasketModel(org_id=1, first_attribute="Hello", second_attribute="World")


# Check if any record exists with those attributes

session.query(BasketModel).filter(
                BasketModel.org_id == entityB.org_id,
                BasketModel.first_attribute == entityB.first_attribute,
                BasketModel.second_attribute == entityB.second_attribute,
                ... # and I have many more
                ).count()
```

This "works fine" because it output what I expected which is duplicated rows bases on values of each field. But it is pretty hard coded.

Is there any way to do something like this, that will check every non keys attributes and check for equality ? (It's weird that I did not found because I am pretty sure that each record is mapped to a kind of set behind the scene in the ORM...which occurrence could be "easily" checked ...

```py
session.query(BasketModel).exists(entityB) # I did not find any API for that...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not your job to check if there is already a value .
Your job is to inert the data and catch eventually an error “duplicated data”
Add to your table an uniq-index on the fields.
You can eventually hash all the fields in one but here again this is not your job. But I’m pretty sure the DB already optimizes it very well.

Comment: I did not tought about simply adding an index and remove this code from the logic ! THank you very much

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to approach this would be to store a hash of the values of the non-key columns in a column with unique constraint.  In this way, we only need to check against a single column when inserting or updating a record.

```py
class MyModel(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    record_hash = Column(String, unique=True)
    ...
```

The hash value is constructed like this (untested):

```py
import hashlib
...

mymodel = MyModel(attr1='a', attr2='b',...)
non_key_cols = sorted(
    filter(lambda c: c.name != 'record_hash' and not c.primary_key, MyModel.__table__.columns
    )
)
hash_vals = [str(getattr(mymodel, col)) for col in non_key_cols]
hash_ = hashlib.sha256(''.join(hash_vals)).hexdigest()
mymodel.record_hash = hash_
session.add(mymodel)
```

There are doubtless neater ways to do this with SQLAlchemy - maybe using [a function to provide a default value](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html?highlight=computed#python-executed-functions), but the above code conveys the general idea.

If an instance with the same non-key values is created or updated, the unique constraint  on `hash_record` will trigger an `IntegrityError` and prevent insertion.

Note that `hash_record` will have to be recomputed when a record is updated, and will have to be recomputed for the entire table if columns are added or removed, or altered in such a way that the string representation of their value changes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those possibilities. I just added an index in the DB, in that way I can move this logic to the db level instead of doing it in my code. Upvote your answer too for the knowledge sharing

Answer (score 1):

you can use UniqueConstraint and catch db error on insert
if you have sqlalchemy this block should run

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker,declarative_base

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///foo_3.db')
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class BasketModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'basket'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    org_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('organization.id'))
    first_attribute = sa.Column(sa.String(2))
    second_attribute = sa.Column(sa.Integer)
    
    __table_args__ = (
        (sa.UniqueConstraint("first_attribute","second_attribute","org_id"),)
      )

class Organization(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organization'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
with Session() as s:
    s.add(Organization())
    s.add(Organization())
    s.commit()
    orgs=s.query(Organization).all()
    print([org.id for org in orgs])
    s.add(BasketModel(org_id=2,first_attribute="AB",second_attribute=2))
    s.commit()
    res=s.query(BasketModel).filter_by(org_id=2).all()
    print(res)
    try:
        s.add(BasketModel(org_id=2,first_attribute="AB",second_attribute=2))
        s.commit()
    except IntegrityError as e:
        print("duplicate row",e)
```

```
[1, 2]
[<__main__.BasketModel object at 0x7f459e9221f0>]
duplicate row (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: basket.first_attribute, basket.second_attribute, basket.org_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO basket (org_id, first_attribute, second_attribute) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: (2, 'AB', 2)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
```

Comment: Great idea to put the constraint on the model declaration. Do you know how to do this with a metadata declaration instead of inherit directly from the declarative base ? Anyway, upvoted your anwer too (it is very close to what I finally did) thank you

Comment: i dont usually use metadata declaration , from the docs looks like you can just add it inside the call to Table() https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.unique

Comment: Maybe this could interests you : https://www.cosmicpython.com/book/chapter_02_repository.html#_the_normal_orm_way_model_depends_on_orm let me know what you thought

Comment: interesting read  thanks for link :) , the code base I am working on is the complete opposite of this approach , but i can see how for some entities it would have been the better approach